# How to arrange items in "Recent Objects" in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do you sort or arrange items in the "Recent Objects" pane in Oracle SQL Developer?  This can be done in the software Toad, using the project manager so I was thinking that this must be available in SQL Developer.  I typically use 5 tables on a daily basis and would like to have them grouped on the side of the screen for easy access.

We are currently using version 3.2.10.09.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, at least not yet.

You can submit that as an enhancement request. They're sorted now by MRU...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this issue is to simply add filters to the connection pane for the tables or packages that are used frequently.